# why does vfork produce this output?

Tags: c, linux, unix, process

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static void f1(void);
static void f2(void);

int main(void)
{
    printf("process id:%d\n", getpid());
    f1();
    f2();
    _exit(0);
}

static void f1(void)
{
    pid_t pid;

    if((pid = vfork()) < 0)
    {
        printf("vfork error\n");
    }
}
static void f2(void)
{
    char buf[1000];
    int i;

    for(i = 0;  i < sizeof(buf); i++)
    {
        buf[i] = 0;
    }

    printf("f2:process id:%d\n", getpid());
}
```

The output of the above program is:

```
process id:9956
f2:process id:9957
```

`Vfork` ensures the child process execute before parent, so I think when return from function `f1()`, child process will execute `f2()`, then `_exit(0)`; After that, why does not the parent process execute the function `f2()`?

Comment: I can find only `fork()` in your example

Comment: @skwllsp sorry, i miss typed the vfork..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you mistyped `fork` instead of `vfork` in the question body. If that is the case you're misusing `vfork`. Once you issue `vfork` you shouldn't do anything in the child other than `exec` or exit.

> The vfork() function has the same effect as fork(2), except that the
>   **behavior is undefined** if the process created by vfork() either
>   modifies any data other than a variable of type pid_t used to store
>   the return value from vfork(), **or returns from the function in which
>   vfork() was called, or calls any other function** before successfully
>   calling _exit(2) or one of the exec(3) family of functions

Comment: do you mean that if I use vfork, then I shouldn't call any functions in the child process?but some basic statements are allowed?

Comment: @Charles0429 You are allowed to exec or to call `_exit`. In particular, you should strive to not change the process space since it belongs to the parent.